# How to keep .txt format when saving to pdf using FPDF (Python)

Tags: python, text, fpdf

I have a .txt file that I'm converting to a PDF using FPDF, however, the format of the .txt is not maintained.
The .txt file looks like this (this is taken from an example online):

[image]

but the PDF I'm creating looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the numbers in the table are all aligned to the right but I would like them to be exactly as they are in the .txt file. Is there a way to do this? My code is as follows:

```
from fpdf import FPDF

pdf = FPDF()   
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font("Arial", size = 10)
f = open("Test", "r")
for x in f:
    pdf.cell(0, 4, txt = x, ln = 1)
filename='/Users/Test.pdf'
pdf.output(filename, 'F')
```

This is what it looks like with a Courier font as per comment:

[image]

Comment: You're choosing Arial as your font in the PDF, but presumably the text file is displayed using a monospaced font?

Comment: @Kemp you could well be right. I'm using the default font in my text file.

Comment: @Kemp I've used a few other fonts but I still have the same issue

Comment: Have you tried a monospaced font specifically? You'd have to check what's available on your system, but ones like "Lucida Console" and "Consolas" should be generally available on Windows for example. If you have the same issue with one of those it'd be worth updating your code and screenshot to show how it looks.

Comment: @ Kemp I've tried "Courier" which is a monospaced font on MacOS but I still have the same issue. I think the problem is that I can only align the cell L, R or C. The screenshots above are with a L or default alignment. No matter what I do I can't seem to keep the same alignment that's on the .txt file.

Comment: The lines in the text file are left-aligned simply because of how text files are displayed, so the alignment shouldn't be an issue. The alignment for each "column" in the text file is simply a matter of how many spaces there are, which is where the monospaced font comes into play. Could you post a screenshot of the output when using a monospaced font?

Comment: @Kemp I've edited my question to show the output with 'Courier' font

Comment: I was able to keep the formatting by first converting the .txt file to a .docx file and then to a PDF file. I'm getting the result that I want but I'm sure there is an easier way to do this.

Comment: That's interesting, it looks like multiple spaces are being collapsed into a single space. For example, the 3 spaces between the values in the Year and CapitalGain columns become 1 space in your output and the 14 spaces between the CapitalGain and Exemption columns values become 4 spaces. That could be a PDF thing but it's going a bit out of my knowledge there. I'd suggest possibly doing a replace on the strings to swap the spaces for some character like a non-breaking space that's less likely to be removed.

Comment: Yes I think you're right. Thank you very much for your time!